# How do i use a {bootstrap} pop-up in a function

Tags: jquery, html

I have page that uses a bootstrap pop up a log in form for log in. I want to use this pop up all over my site in that when in the sign up page I have a log in link that will pop up the log in form which is in form of a blur.

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="page-header">
<header>
    <!--<div id="logo">
            <h5><a href="gallery.php" style="text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #fff; font-size: 32px;margin-top: -10px;">K-Movies</a></h5>
    </div>-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="h.php" style="text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #fff; font-size: 32px;">K-Movies</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Categories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:blue;"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" style="color:blue;"></span> Login</a>

                        <!-- Modal  The pop {blur}-->

                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                             <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <!-- Modal content-->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        Log In Form
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form method="POST" action="login.php" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                              <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" class="control-label col-sm-4">
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pw">Password:</label>
                                                <input type="password" name="pw" class="control-label col-sm-4">
                                            </div>  

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
                                                    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button> <b>OR</b> <br><strong><a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></strong>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form> 
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>    
</header>
</div>
```

And here is the link in a different page

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button><b>OR</b> <strong><a href="" onclick="mylogin()">Log In</a></strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the breaks im new here still dont know how to use this

Comment: What problem you are facing into this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {

var $formLogin = $('#login-form');
var $formLost = $('#lost-form');
var $formRegister = $('#register-form');
var $divForms = $('#div-forms');
var $modalAnimateTime = 300;
var $msgAnimateTime = 150;
var $msgShowTime = 2000;

$("form").submit(function () {
    switch(this.id) {
        case "login-form":
            var $lg_username=$('#login_username').val();
            var $lg_password=$('#login_password').val();
            if ($lg_username == "ERROR") {
                msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Login error");
            } else {
                msgChange($('#div-login-msg'), $('#icon-login-msg'), $('#text-login-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Login OK");
            }
            return false;
            break;
        case "lost-form":
            var $ls_email=$('#lost_email').val();
            if ($ls_email == "ERROR") {
                msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Send error");
            } else {
                msgChange($('#div-lost-msg'), $('#icon-lost-msg'), $('#text-lost-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Send OK");
            }
            return false;
            break;
        case "register-form":
            var $rg_username=$('#register_username').val();
            var $rg_email=$('#register_email').val();
            var $rg_password=$('#register_password').val();
            if ($rg_username == "ERROR") {
                msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "error", "glyphicon-remove", "Register error");
            } else {
                msgChange($('#div-register-msg'), $('#icon-register-msg'), $('#text-register-msg'), "success", "glyphicon-ok", "Register OK");
            }
            return false;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return false;
});

$('#login_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formRegister) });
$('#register_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLogin); });
$('#login_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLogin, $formLost); });
$('#lost_login_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formLogin); });
$('#lost_register_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formLost, $formRegister); });
$('#register_lost_btn').click( function () { modalAnimate($formRegister, $formLost); });

function modalAnimate ($oldForm, $newForm) {
    var $oldH = $oldForm.height();
    var $newH = $newForm.height();
    $divForms.css("height",$oldH);
    $oldForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime, function(){
        $divForms.animate({height: $newH}, $modalAnimateTime, function(){
            $newForm.fadeToggle($modalAnimateTime);
        });
    });
}

function msgFade ($msgId, $msgText) {
    $msgId.fadeOut($msgAnimateTime, function() {
        $(this).text($msgText).fadeIn($msgAnimateTime);
    });
}

function msgChange($divTag, $iconTag, $textTag, $divClass, $iconClass, $msgText) {
    var $msgOld = $divTag.text();
    msgFade($textTag, $msgText);
    $divTag.addClass($divClass);
    $iconTag.removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
    $iconTag.addClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
    setTimeout(function() {
        msgFade($textTag, $msgOld);
        $divTag.removeClass($divClass);
        $iconTag.addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");
        $iconTag.removeClass($iconClass + " " + $divClass);
    }, $msgShowTime);
}
});
```

[Check here.](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/modal-login-with-jquery-effects)

Comment: Actually its a simple modal popup which is already included login page so as per your question you want to use it any of your page in your application so just only copy paste the modal forms including jquery files and change the id names as per your need.